# Why is a type annotation needed on a function that declares more generic types than it uses?

Tags: rust

```
fn lifetime_tester<A, B, C>(a: Box<A>, b: Box<B>, c: &i32) -> &i32 {
    c
}

fn main() {
    let a = Box::new(String::from("Test1"));
    let b = Box::new(55 as i32);
    let c: i32;
    {
        c = 34 as i32;
    }
    println!("{}", lifetime_tester(a, b, &c));
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:12:20
   |
12 |     println!("{}", lifetime_tester(a, b, &c));
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `C`
```

I am baffled about where a "type annotation" needs to go. I've specified a return type as `&i32`, I've specified an argument type of `&i32` and I've also specified that `c` is an `i32`.

Comment: I'm no rust expert, but it seems like the problem is that you never mention the generic parameter (uppercase) C in the function, so it can't infer its type from the arguments.  So you probably need to drop C or explicitly supply the types when calling lifetime_tester

Comment: There is no link between `C` and `c`, your [MCVE] don't make much sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is no link between the arguments to your function and the generic type `C`, the compiler has no idea which type you mean to replace `C` in the function call. In this case your code doesn't even use the type `C` so it doesn't matter, but Rust is big about "local reasoning" - i.e. it won't peek inside your function to determine you're not using `C` at the syntax checking stage.

You can explicitly tell it what your types are using the "turbofish" operator, `::<>`, like this

```
println!("{}", lifetime_tester::<_, _, i32>(a, b, &c));
```